# Probability for normal distribution within [-x/2, x/2] that more than 1/4 of the values are not hit

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Given a **normal distribution** and a **discrete** value range of **[-x/2, x/2]**, what is the chance, that out of **n tries**, at least **1/4** of the possible values are **never hit**?

It is not relevant which 1/4 of the x possible values are hit or not. Therefore, the values which are not hit do not have to be a consecutive part of the value range (e.g. [x/4, x/2]) and do not have to follow a specific pattern (e.g. every fourth value is not hit) but can be randomly distributed over the value range.

PS: This is my first question, so I would appreciate suggestions to improve the question.

**Edit:**

The intention behind this question is as follows:
Audio files consist of a list of integer values(=samples) within a specific range. This range depends on the volume of the audio and is more or less symmetrical around 0, because these values behave like waves, so they go over 0, then under 0, then over 0 again and so on. For this reason, values around 0 occur pretty often, while values at the top and bottom of the range are rare.

If you double the volume of an "original" audio file, you basically just double all sample values. Therefore the overall range also doubles, but in respect to the new range the ratio of values realized decreases. Of course this also works the other way around: Halve the volume and the new range halves but the ratio of values realized increases.

My ultimate goal now is to detect if the volume of a given file was changed and therefore find some kind of rule to distinguish edited from unedited files.

For an unedited audio file I observed the following:
n = 1323000 samples
value range = [-7883, 8960]
4327 values of the value range are never "realized" by the n samples.

Since this is an unedited ("original") file, this "range to values realized" ratio is what I would expect from an unedited file. Of course the amount of samples also plays a role here.

Since im not very experienced in probability distributions, I might have mixed up the term "normal distribution" here.

This is how the values are roughly distributed, and maybe this explains why I think of normal distribution: https://i.stack.imgur.com/krK5e.jpg

Comment: A normal distribution is absolutely continuous, which also means that any discrete set as measure $0$. Which means that the probability of hitting anything in this set in $n$ tries is $0$. Thus your probability should be $1$.

Comment: @Lazy Okay maybe I got that wrong. So let's assume it is not a normal distribution, since it just hits integers in given range, but the distribution of the values hit is like a normal distribution. Is there a way to calculate the original problem?

Comment: @Kühlhausvogel You would have to be more precise about what you mean by "the distribution of the values hit is like a normal distribution."  If you mean it's a large binomial, then sure, that could be calculated.  But the more like a normal distribution it is, the closer that probability will get to $0$.

Comment: @user6247850 Thank you for pointing this out. I updated the question, adding the intention behind the question. Maybe this helps to understand my problem, while I don't "misuse" any mathematical terms

Comment: Yeah, I think approximating that with a normal would be reasonable, but the probability of a normal random variable being an integer is $0$.  The reason for my and Lazy's response isn't that we were upset with "misusing" any mathematical terms, it's just that the question couldn't be answered as stated.  Maybe, instead of looking at the probability of a normal RV being an integer $n$, you could look at the probability of it falling in the range $(n-.5,n+.5)$?  Tangentially, is there any reason to think there's significance to some values never being realized in the samples?

Comment: @user6247850 Thanks again for answering! I, again, updated the question to give even more information about my goal and the intention behind it. Also, For me it sounds like we have to dismiss the whole "normal distribution" stuff and handle it as a binomial distribution.

Comment: A binomial distribution is well-approximated by a normal distribution when the number of samples is large, but regardless a binomial distribution doesn't work directly here since it models the number of successes in a series of trials.  I think it's far easier to approximate this by rounding a normal distribution than trying to find some way to translate it to a binomial distribution.

Comment: @user6247850 okay so since I am pretty unexperienced with probability distributions and calculations, do you have a suggestion of how to calculate this?